# RSpec: failure Cabybara Webkit InvalidResponseError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec-rails, filepicker.io, capybara-webkit

I'm getting this error on a dozen or so failing specs. Other devs on my team (and our CI) aren't seeing these failing specs so it's a problem local to my kit.

Edit: first 6 lines are an excerpt from capybara-webkit's :webkit_debug driver:

```
...
Started request to "https://dialog.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/"
Started request to "https://www.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/"
Received "Evaluate((typeof angular !== 'undefined') && angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).length > 0)"
"TimeoutCommand" waiting for load to finish
Received 0 from "https://dialog.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/"
Page finished with false
...

  1) User edits profile information
     Failure/Error: click_on t('users.edit')
     Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
       Unable to load URL: http://127.0.0.1:53899/myprofile?as=1089 because of error loading https://dialog.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/: Unknown error
     # ./spec/features/users_spec.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:5:in `run_background_jobs_immediately'
     # ./spec/support/background_jobs.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I troubleshoot this?  Is this somehow AngularJS related?!?

Edit2: error is thrown on `visit` path (see below). Adding `save_and_open_page` one line before just opens an empty page. Putting anything after line 30 never gets called because of error. Adding `binding.pry` on 29 gets me to console but I'm not really sure what I should be looking for to troubleshoot this.

```
     25:   scenario 'edits profile information', js: true do
     26:     new_avatar = 'http://example.com/avatar.png'
     27:     user = create(:user)
     28:
  => 29:     binding.pry
     30:     visit myprofile_path(as: user)
     31:     click_on t('users.edit')
     32:     edit_profile(name: 'Edit User', avatar: new_avatar)
     33:     visit myprofile_path
     34:
     35:     expect(page).to have_text('Edit User')
```

Comment: add a save_and_open_page before the error and see if you are on the right page with the right elements.

Comment: `save_and_open_page` doesn't appear to do anything…

Comment: add gem 'launchy' in your gemfile and try again

Comment: add gem 'pry' in your gemfile, add a binding.pry before the error, run the test, in the console type in save_and_open_age, what does it say?

Comment: ok, see edit2 above.

Comment: post information about myprofile_path like the method or the route

Comment: maybe it should just be visit myprofile_path(user)

Comment: `myprofile  GET  /myprofile(.:format)` routes to `users#show`.  Thing is these specs pass on my laptop, other dev's boxes *and* on our CI server. I just can't figure out why this is failing only on my main dev box. Driving me nuts!  Appreciate your help though…

Comment: I am seeing the same issue on my project. Also as in your case, it is not affecting some people on my team or our CI server (but at least a couple of my teammates are getting the error). Also, I think I started seeing it on the same day as you, April 9th 2015. A day earlier, Apple pushed out an OS X Update to Yosemite version 10.10.3 ( https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?locale=en_US ) and I installed the update. Some of my teammates did too, but not all. Our CI server is semaphore and I'm pretty sure that's not running OS X. So far the ones who have the error also updated to 10.10.3.

Comment: I am not certain whether the new OS X version actually caused the error, or how it might have done so (one teammate commented that some OpenSSL-related things had changed or broken, so maybe related to that?), or how the error can be fixed, but I'd love to know what others find out as this is still causing failing specs on my project.

Comment: I'll keep monitoring this in hopes of a better answer. Until then tests pass on Semaphore but will fail locally unless I blacklist some Filepicker URLs (see my 'answer' below).

Comment: Having this problem too--blocking requests is not an option (since that's what we're testing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up blocking those requests altogether `spec_helper.rb`:

```
  config.before :each, js: true do
    page.driver.browser.url_blacklist = [
      "https://dialog.filepicker.io",
      "https://www.filepicker.io"
    ]
  end
```